# How can I store a Photo image on an html5 sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, html, photo

I would like an html5 page that runs in Android 2.2 Browser that I can take a picture using the phone's built-in camera and save it to a sqlite database as a blob.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work with an HTML5 only application.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phoneGap.com) it can solve you problem; because like Octavian said, a plain HTML5 web app will not do what you are requesting.

[PhoneGap Camera API](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494789/iPhone%3a-Camera-API)